# Extend http class and access custom properties (Angular2 typescript)

Tags: typescript, angular

I created CustomHttp class which extends Http like here: http://restlet.com/blog/2016/04/18/interacting-efficiently-with-a-restful-service-with-angular2-and-rxjs-part-3/#comment-83563

I added providers to bootstrap like this:

```
bootstrap([
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    { provide:Http,
        useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, errorNotifier: NotificationHandlerService, 
                     authService: AuthInfoService) => {
            return new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, errorNotifier, authService);
        },
        deps: [ XHRBackend, RequestOptions, NotificationHandlerService,  AuthInfoService]
    },
  ])
```

All overriden methods(get, post, etc.) work fine. Then I added custom property and method to CustomHttp class and tried to access the property outside CustomHttp:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {

...
private myCustomProperty = 'It`s custom';

public getCustomProperty() {
    return this.myCustomProperty;
}
...

}
```

=====================

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

export class MainComponent {

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
       this._http.getCustomProperty(); // this method doesn`t exist in Http
    }
}
```

How can I access custom methods and properties of CustomHttp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following by casting the `Http` instance to `CustomHttp`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { CustomHttp } from './custom.http';

@Injectable()
export class BooksService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    console.log((<CustomHttp>this.http).someProperty);
  }

  (...)
}
```

with the following `CustomHttp` class:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  someProperty:string = 'some string';

  (...)
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Is it a good way to use CustomHttp like this?

Comment: You're welcome! I don't know exactly your use case, but generally, we try to "hide" the subclass against the `Http` one... That being said, it's not false to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {CustomHttp} from '/path';

export class MainComponent {

    constructor(private _http: CustomHttp) {
       this._http.getCustomProperty(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".