# How to handle exception uniformly / globally for Angular2 / Typescript observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

All over the tutorial for Angular2 I see that exceptions are being caught right where the call is, e.g.:

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

While this might be good for the tutorial, this does not sound sustainable for me. I would like to have some global handler that will e.g. overlay/popup some message to a user and log the error to console + override it when I need some special handling (e.g. if I read the json error and find that I can handle it in a more user-friendly way than just a popup for one of the components), without the need to override it everywhere like the example from Angular2 suggests.

Is it possible to achieve?

P.S. A C# analogue would be some global.asax `Application_Error` + `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` error handling for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way you can make all Observables do some globally predefined behavior.

Since you probably want to handle mostly request from `http` in some uniform way you can replace the default `http` service with your own that extends methods such as `get()` or `post()` and always append `catch()` or `retryWhen()` operators. See:

- [Extend http class and access custom properties (Angular2 typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438020/extend-http-class-and-access-custom-properties-angular2-typescript)
- [How to extend angular 2 http class in Angular 2 final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675806/how-to-extend-angular-2-http-class-in-angular-2-final)

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, I don't think the http is throwing an exception, not in the usual sense. It is calling the catch delegate when a HTTP error code is received.

From reading around you can catch globally thrown errors like in C# using the [ErrorHandler](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html) but in your promise you will still have to throw it like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482173/errorhandler-in-angular2)